# LLVM IR: find_if, var not captured

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

So I have following snippet in my code

```
  for (inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I){
    Instruction *Inst = &*I;
    if (isa<LoadInst>(Inst)) {
      LoadInst *LI = dyn_cast<LoadInst>(Inst);
      Value * LoadOperand = LI -> getPointerOperand();
      auto it = std::find_if(DataStructureForTrace.begin(), DataStructureForTrace.end(), [](const std::tuple<Value*, unsigned, unsigned, Value* >& e) {return *(std::get<3>(e)) == *(LoadOperand);});
      std::get<2>(*it) = 1;
    }
 }
```

In the line 6, I get error as: `LoadOperand` not captured.

I had tried a dummy (not of LLVM type, just normal C++ code) implementation to see if such thing works, and it did function properly. Now here I am not sure if the error is associated with LLVM or generic C++.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is referring to the fact that you aren't capturing `LoadOperand` in the lambda expression in the call to `std::find_if`.  You can capture it by reference with `[&LoadOperand]` as in this expression:

```
std::find_if(DataStructureForTrace.begin(), DataStructureForTrace.end(), [&LoadOperand](const std::tuple<Value*, unsigned, unsigned, Value* >& e) {return *(std::get<3>(e)) == *(LoadOperand);});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. So this should have been there: `[&LoadOperand]`? Can you please add some more explanation? In the dummy code, when I used just `int pointer`s it worked with `[]`. Why not now?

Comment: Variables in the body of the lambda that aren't passed in as function arguments need to be captured inside the brackets.  Not sure why your other example was working, unless it just didn't refer to any such variables.

Comment: Okay, understood. My other example was working because I was comparing against an int value and not variable. I am sorry for the confusion.